# angular 2 - radio button two way binding, get values in a hidden element

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms, radio-group, two-way-binding

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/wykFqdlWzmTePXXtonCu?p=preview)**

I am loading form from JSON.

I need help on below issue.

**Issue :** On click of save button i need to get the radio button values either **true** or **false**

but now i am getting both radio button values as '**true** in console'

**Users can click both the buttons, since it is a radio group, i need one value as true and another one as false vice versa**

```
{name: "rado 1", type: "radio", id: "rOne", checked: true}
{name: "radio 2", type: "radio", id: "rTwo", checked: true}
```

My component HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-12  pb-2 pt-4">
  <form class="form-horizontal">


  <div *ngFor="let record of records"> 
  <div *ngFor="let radioButton of record.wrapper">

      <label>

        //hidden element 
        <input  type="hidden" name="{{radioButton.id}}" [(ngModel)]="radioButton.checked">

        <input 

        name="radiogroup" 

        type="radio" 

        id="{{radioButton.id}}"

        [checked]="radioButton.checked" 

        (change)="radioButton.checked = $event.target.checked" 

        [value]="radioButton.checked" 
                > 
                {{radioButton.name}}  
      </label>

  </div>
  </div>

<button class=" btn btn-primary " href="# " (click)="save() ">Save</button>

</form>
</div>`
```

**Expected:** I need radio button values true or false vice versa, it can not be both true or false.

- values should be sent to hidden variables.
- Two way binding

My Json (i have very complex json but here making it simple one)

```
[
  {
    "wrapper": [
          {
            "name": "rado 1",
            "type": "radio",
            "id": "rOne",
            "checked": false
          },
          {
            "name": "radio 2",
            "type": "radio",
            "id": "rTwo",
            "checked": false
          }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

```
  <label>
    <input 

    name="radiogroup" 

    type="radio" 

    id="{{radioButton.id}}"
    [value] = "radioButton.id"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioId" > 
            {{radioButton.name}}  
  </label>
```

ts :

```
 // On click of save button show console log with values
  save(): void {
    this.records[0].wrapper.forEach((wrapper)=>{
      wrapper.checked = wrapper.id == this.selectedRadioId;
    })
    console.log(this.records[0].wrapper[0]);
    console.log(this.records[0].wrapper[1]);
  }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lqpG67qUCcFk01nOfd0D?p=preview)

Comment: i tried, please check https://plnkr.co/edit/KJYniG1tiqrzzxbLlTNK?p=preview , always radio 2 is selected.

Comment: Ooh ok wait a minute

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot. i was stuck with this issue for many days.

Comment: i have one issue with your plunker,
its not reading the data for e.g: 'checked:true' in json, radio button is not selected, please check, https://plnkr.co/edit/JSJRTQDdz52kYqvF6tzR?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot now it is fixed. great help, keep the good work.